# Dynamic Images in BIP Template?

Tags: templates, rtf, bi-publisher

We have set of images in a shared path. In the query we have written a logic that would give us the path of the image something like **\\path\Logos\
test.jpg** . In the RTF template, we have used a dummy image with the **Alt Text** set to the path of the image like **url:{PATH_FIELD}**. In the run time, instead of dummy image, the image we need comes up. This only works if the output is in HTML. We need the output to be in PDF. For PDF outputs, the image is not getting displayed. It just shows a white blank space. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the altenative text, the path field should have the full path like
url:{DATA_DS/GROUP_TAG_NAME/PATH_FIELD}. I hope this will work with PDF output